# Ajax.post --> dom.fetch

Tags: ajax, fetch, scala.js

I'm trying to use the dom.fetch (or dom.Fetch.fetch) api instead of Ajax.post and have a few problems:

Is this a correct translation from ajax to fetch?

```scala
Ajax.post(
  url = "http://localhost:8080/ajax/myMethod",
  data = byteBuffer2typedArray(Pickle.intoBytes(req.payload)),
  responseType = "arraybuffer",
  headers = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/octet-stream"),
)

dom.fetch(
  "http://localhost:8080/fetch/myMethod",
  new RequestInit {
    method = HttpMethod.POST
    body = byteBuffer2typedArray(Pickle.intoBytes(req.payload))
    headers = new Headers {
      js.Array(
        js.Array("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
      )
    }
  }
)
```

A "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined" is thrown on the js side though, same if replacing with `dom.Fetch.fetch`.

My setup:

Fresh jsdom 19.0.0 with

```
npm init private
npm install jsdom
```

project/plugins.sbt

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-env-jsdom-nodejs" % "1.1.0"
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.8.0")
```

build.sbt (in js project)

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "2.0.0"
jsEnv := new JSDOMNodeJSEnv(JSDOMNodeJSEnv.Config()
  .withArgs(List("--dns-result-order=ipv4first")))
```

Thought that the jsEnv workaround was not needed on Scala.js 1.8 (see https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-js-envs/issues/12#issuecomment-958925883). But it is still needed when I run the ajax version. With the workaround, my ajax version works fine, so it seems that my node installation is fine.

Comment: You can do headers = js.Dictionary("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fetch` API is only available by-default in browser environments, and not in Node. `node-fetch` is also not pulled in (or at least not re-exported) by `jsdom`, so `fetch` is not available with the current package/environment setup.

Possible solutions:

1. Set the ScalaJS side up in such a way that it would call `node-fetch` on NodeJS and `fetch` on browser
2. Use XMLHttpRequest which is available on both platforms

(Please see [the #scala-js channel](https://discord.com/channels/632150470000902164/635668814956068864/922275560695160852) in the Scala Discord for a related conversation).

Comment: fwiw a link to a specific Discord channel won't stand up to the test of time. If you include the relevant parts here in your answer then people years down the line will still be able to benefit from the information :)

Comment: Sounds good, I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Aly - thought that it's better if we communicate here than on Discord. I don't see any reason to delete your answer. Was it just to see if it was possible or were there another reason that I have missed?

Comment: I just didn't figure my answer has the more useful set of information. At least if you don't want it deleted, I'd argue that it shouldn't be marked as the correct answer 

Comment: (Feedback: screenshots of off-site conversations don't really contribute to the point of Stack Overflow. Screenshots of text don't work with screen-readers, search engines, or clipboards. Links tend to die over time (though I acknowledge that Discord conversations are not often deleted), and links requiring an account tend to present more frustration than utility. In general, if it is possible to copy a summary of a conversation here, in text format, that is ideal).

Answer (score 2):

Got help on the scala-js channel on Discord from @Aly [here](https://discord.com/channels/632150470000902164/635668814956068864/921818047830954034) and @armanbilge [here](https://discord.com/channels/632150470000902164/635668814956068864/921841387677310996) who pointed out that:

- `fetch` is not available by default in Node.js or JSDOM, only in browsers.
- scala-js-dom provides typesafe access to browser APIs, not Node.js APIs.

The distinction between browser API and Node API wasn't clear for me before, although it is well described in step 6 of the [scala-js tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial/basic/).

So, `dom.fetch` of the scala-js-dom API works when running a js program in a browser, but not if running a test that uses the Node jsEnv(ironment)! To fetch in a test one would have to `npm install node-fetch` and use `node-fetch`, maybe by making a facade with scala-js.

Since I want my code to work for both browser (scala-js-dom) and test (Node.js), I ended up falling back to simply using the Ajax.post implementation with XMLHttpRequest:

```scala
case class PostException(xhr: dom.XMLHttpRequest) extends Exception {
  def isTimeout: Boolean = xhr.status == 0 && xhr.readyState == 4
}

val url         = s"http://$interface:$port/ajax/" + slothReq.path.mkString("/")
val byteBuffer  = Pickle.intoBytes(slothReq.payload)
val requestData = byteBuffer.typedArray().subarray(byteBuffer.position, byteBuffer.limit)
val req         = new dom.XMLHttpRequest()
val promise     = Promise[dom.XMLHttpRequest]()

req.onreadystatechange = { (e: dom.Event) =>
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if ((req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) || req.status == 304)
      promise.success(req)
    else
      promise.failure(PostException(req))
  }
}
req.open("POST", url) // (I only need to POST)
req.responseType = "arraybuffer"
req.timeout = 0
req.withCredentials = false
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
req.send(requestData)

promise.future.recover {
  case PostException(xhr) =>
    val msg    = xhr.status match {
      case 0 => "Ajax call failed: server not responding."
      case n => s"Ajax call failed: XMLHttpRequest.status = $n."
    }
    println(msg)
    xhr
}.flatMap { req =>
  val raw       = req.response.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
  val dataBytes = TypedArrayBuffer.wrap(raw.slice(1))
  Future.successful(dataBytes)
}
```